# In my Android pollen app, I am adding a tip box. Should this be a pop up or something else?

Tags: android

I am currently working on an Android app for getting daily updates on the status of pollen.

Here is a work-in-progress screenshot:

[image]

Upon getting some feedback from people, I am going to restructure the way the data is placed:

EditText

City Name

Date of Today

Pollen Index
Pollen Type

Tomorrow -- Day After Tomorrow

My question is four-fold:

1. What would be the best way to display the data I currently have in a user experience friendly manner? I got some feedback saying the number, i.e. `8.30/10` is confusing. So I plan on adding a label right below saying "Pollen Severity".
2. I am adding a tip box to deal with allergies on those particularly bad days. Should this be a pop-up box? A hover box? Under the pollen index so users don't need to press any buttons?
3. I am interested in adding a legend to the pollen index. What is the best way to do it without cluttering the minimalist interface?
4. Additional feedback on my interface?

Thank you.

Comment: I would agree that the 8.30/10 is confusing, especially with the /10 being do small. When I first glanced at it, I thought it was a time.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage In it's current form this question is likly going to be closed as site reviews are off-topic for ux.stackexchange.com. It would be good if the question was phrased in a more general way so that it's also helpful for other use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In my opinion, the way you are going to display the "8.30/10" depends on your users but most of the time, it would effectively be a good idea to put a text label under it.
- What do you mean by "tip box" is it a box that tells to your users what to do when there is a problem ? In this case a pop-up box seems to be the better one because a hover box includes that your user need to keep his finger on the button, which seems pretty bad for the UX if the user needs read the text easily. Under the pollen index doesn't feel useful to me expect if you need to warn you user from a danger.
- Well, writing it with the same appearance than the pollen type would feel good for me. Add this legend under the pollen index.
- Yes, It would feel more natural, In my opinion, to put it not out of ten but in percentage (something such as 83%, which people might be more used to). I would also have putted the pollen type under the pollen index. Also, why not directly locating the user instead of prompting him to enter his ZIP code ? If you want him to enter his ZIP code anyway you should do that on an other panel (such as the settings panel) because most of the time your user probably won't change often of location or if he does let him enter several locations on which he can easily navigate.

EDIT :
Also, why not displaying a photo of the city, a little bit like what Yahoo Weather does ?

EDIT #2 (responding to your comment) :
It's true that it's pretty difficult for a user that doesn't know what this level exactly means and how they should interpret it.
 *To give you my opinion, if you tell me "8.3 out of 10", I will assume that it's a pretty high level, but if you tell me "5.5 out of 10" I will be hesitating to know wether it presents a big risk of allergy or not.* "Allergy Severity : Medium-High" seems better than "Today's Allergy Level" because your users already know that it's the today's one.
So you need to choose between "Allergy Severity" and "Allergy level", as you might have guessed I'm not a native english speaker, so I am hesitating to determine which one is the best. This is just a suggestion, but "Allergy hasard" seems pretty good too.
About your tips, if it's just one line tips it feels more natural, in my opinion, to display it directly under the pollen index.

Comment: One major concern people have had were "`what does that 8.3/10 number mean?`" How do you think I can alleviate that concern? The number indicates allergy severity based on Pollen.org's description: http://www.pollen.com/allergy-forecast.asp Should I consider something like "`Allergy Severity: Medium-High`" immediately under `pollen type` or `pollen severity number`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Or even "Today's Allergy Level:"

Comment: A tip box is basically tips on dealing with allergies for that particular day. For example, a simple one-liner, if the index is higher than 8, that it is good to stay indoors or get allergy medicine.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Take a look at my answer, I edited it to answer to your comments :)